# "who am i" in ansible and over ssh outputs nothing

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, command-line, ansible

I have the following test code in ansible:

```
- shell: who am i
  register: w

- debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ w }}"
```

which produces empty stdout as shown below:

```
ok: [10.20.30.40] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "who am i",
            "delta": "0:00:00.003400",
            "end": "2021-02-02 21:19:50.454729",
            "failed": false,
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2021-02-02 21:19:50.451329",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "",
            "stdout_lines": []
        }
    ]
}
```

The command works on some servers, but not work on some others. I could not figure out what the difference is.
I can only guess it has to do with terminal info. When I type the "who am i" command interactively, I get
what I expected.

I also noticed the other strange behavior in "who" command over ssh:

```
$ ssh myhost who       # who outputs nothing
$ ssh myhost who am i  # who am i outputs nothing
$ ssh myhost whoami    # whoami works
j.smith
```

Maybe they are related.

I need to use `who am i` in sudo command to find the user who issue the sudo. If there is another way
to find the info, I would be glad to use that, but I still want to know what is happening with `who am i`.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`whoami` shows the username of the current effective user.

`who am i` aka `who -m` shows the utmp record of whatever stdin is.

`utmp` records are generally added by `login` and various kinds of terminal emulators. If you don't create a login session, `who am i` will be blank:

```
$ ssh localhost who am i
(nothing)

$ ssh -t localhost who am i
me    pts/31       Feb  2 14:27 (127.0.0.1)
```

If you e.g. run `screen` with `deflogin off`, then `who am i` will always be blank. This is one reason why you should never use `who am i` to try to figure out who ran `sudo` (use `$SUDO_USER` instead).

Comment: `who am I` has been working on ansible (nonempty output) until we set `pipelining = True` under `[ssh_connection]`. $SUDO_USER is easy but is not reliable since it can be changed. I ended up with using `whomi` outside the sudo task of ansible and register a variable.

Comment: `SUDO_USER` is set by `sudo` and can't be changed by the user, only by the invoked process. If you have whitelisted a safe set of commands, then `SUDO_USER` is both safe and reliable.

Comment: You can change it. Nothing prevents you from setting SUDO_USER=foo in your script.

Comment: Setting SUDO_USER in the script that calls `sudo` has no effect. `sudo` does not pass on this variable.

Comment: True, but setting `SUDO_USER` in the script that `sudo` calls, not the script that call `sudo`, does have effect. It is just like `$HOME` which may not be your real home.

Comment: The script can choose to ignore or overwrite the information, but it's the root user has to explicitly program the script to do this which means they want this to be allowed. The same is true for `who am i`, except the user can also trivially hide the name intentionally or accidentally with `sudo foo < myfile`